# How to use .env.testing file in pest / phpunit and package development?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, php-pest

I am using [Spatie Package Skelton](https://github.com/spatie/package-skeleton-laravel) to develop a package. It is using pest under the hood.
I created a `.env.testing` file and checked the environment used while running a pest test with `dd(app()->environment));`, which is `testing`.

Anyhow, when I use `env('TEST');` in my test and having `TEST=test` in my `.env.testing` file, is it returning `null`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use `.env` files in your package. I created multiple Laravel package and php SDK, with PHPUnit and it never required `.env` file.

If you are fully commited to use Pest, my answer won't be useful.

However if you want to use PHPUnit, then you can create a `phpunit.xml.dist` file. It's just a skeleton and it can be (git) versioned. (Just like `.env.example` in Laravel.)

Make a copy of it and name it `phpunit.xml`. This file should not versioned.
By default PHPunit will looking for this file, or fall back for the dist file.

In this file you can provide environment variables for your test:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
    <other-setting-that-not-relevant-now />
    <php>
        <env name="MY_ENV_KEY" value="my_env_value" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

*This example code might be out-of-date.*

---

Also you should not use `env()` in your package, since [Laravel can cache the configs](https://laravel.com/docs/configuration#configuration-caching). If there is a config cache file, then `env()` will always return `null`.
Register your own config file, you can use `env()` here, and merge it in your provider.
This way you can use `config()` function, but way better solution if you collect the config in your provider, then pass it down to your service class.

Comment: I am very new to all of this and year answer helped me a ton. And most importantly: It's working! Thank you!

Comment: PHPUnit doesn't use `.env` or `.env.testing`, Laravel does; the latter is for cases where you need different configurations set during tests. Unless you enjoy storing credentials in your codebase, you cannot (and should not) easily avoid using `.env` files in a Laravel app.

Comment: In my opinion (almost) every package should be independent from the project or the 3rd-party service. I mean, if you have to test the package's logic inside your app, then it is not really a package.